# Retrieving form value with jQuery

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

Sadly, this isn't as cut and dry as I had hoped. Over the past few weeks I had been researching the use of jQuery with CRM. While it's nice and dandy for style alterations, I couldn't find any examples that are closer to business logic.

For example, today I needed to alert the browser if one of 4 fields were empty. Two were date fields, one a picklist and one a checkbox (bit). I thought that calling $("#formElement").val() would have gotten the value, and in some cases it did, such as the picklist after I parsed it as an int. However, the date fields always returned an empty string.

Looking through the CRM form HTML, I see that "#formElement" isn't always the ID of an input for a CRM form element. Case in point, the date fields had ID="DateTime" (or something similar). At this point, I had thought that I will need to create a filter that will take the table that contains #formElement as it's ID and look for the value of the first input in that table, but at that point using crmForm.all.formElement.DataValue just seemed easier.

I'm sure someone here has a solution for this (and maybe some explaination of how CRM Forms are written to help with a filter), and it really stinks not being able to install add-ons for Internet Explorer here at work. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is looking for an answer, I have figured it out to a managable degree. Unfortuantely, I haven't been able to use CSS selectors to shorten attribute names, but I have been able to utilize jQuery to cut down on time. If you'd like to use a CRM 4 attribute with jQuery, it looks like this:

```
$(crmForm.all.new_attribute).bind("click", function() { ClickFunction(); });
```

What I was really gunning for was chaining, because there are plenty of times when I need to null a field, disable it, and then force it to submit. A little bit of magic and this:

```
crmForm.all.new_attribute.DataValue = null;
crmForm.all.new_attribute.Disable = true;
crmForm.all.new_attribute.ForceSubmit = true;
```

Becomes:

```
crmForm.all.new_attribute.dataValue().disable().forceSubmit();
```

I hope this helps some of you guys out!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to select the form itself (either by its ID or just by $(form)) and then iterate over its [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) that are input text fields. I haven't done this for a form before but it might work for you.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'd have to manually know what index each field is. Looking at it more in-depth, it seems like no matter what the case, it will always fall into _table#formElement input_ and the input may or may not have it's own ID. I haven't given it a shot now -- we have massive JS files for our entities (and honestly for 4 lines of code it's not worth inserting jQuery) but I'll give it a shot in my next CRM project.

Comment: You don't have to do it manually. There's another jQuery method [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) which returns all children of a certain type. You can then iterate over them and or each ID have a switch to process the contents.

Comment: That wouldn't work either. "Regular" text boxes have the ID set to the Form Element's name, but other text boxes (for special data like Dates) have special IDs that do not correspond to their form element name. I also couldn't just look for table#formElement > input because some of them are <selects>.